Can a court 'file' a warrant?
Does 'to file' have the meaning of 'to issue'?
I know that 'to file' means 'to submit to an authority' which is different from 'to issue'. But I see the news title of the Wall Street Journal 2024-11-24.

Global Court Files Warrant To Arrest Netanyahu

In the report the reporters wrote

The International Criminal Court issued arrest warrants for Israeli Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu and former Defense Minister Yoav Gallant, ...

They used those words interchangeably. Is it correct?

I wouldn't say they're "interchangeable". As this usage chart shows, arrest warrants are much more likely to be issued. But the filed version definitely occurs, and it's pointless nit-picking  to complain about it. You should stick with the more common verb yourself, though, obviously. (Unless you're typesetting a newspaper headline and need to save a letter! :)

I would also suspect this is a matter of style and may vary based on what court system you are dealing with. The ICC is a very different beast from US courts, for example.

I would have understood the wording to mean that the warrant is filed (with the police) after it is issued (by a judge). Or perhaps a request for a warrant is filed before the warrant is issued. Not an expert on any legal system.

@SoronelHaetir - even native speakers get judicial-system terms wrong. Many British folk think that they can 'press charges', that courts 'file' warrants, and that the past participle of 'plead' is 'pled' (well, it is in Scotland - in the rest of the UK it's 'pleaded'. I blame American TV dramas).

The two verbs can be used as shown in the examples.
The construction filed an arrest warrant is much less common  than the issued version.
Ngram
In fact, many of the former's hits are false positives and have descriptions like file, an arrest warrant is issued.
The graphs for an arrest warrant is (or 'was') issued show that these usages are also more common than the filed an arrest warrant version inflated ten times.
I usually stick with the more common usage.

The international arrest warrant is  formally presented to, or "filed with", the relevant policing authorities.

The warrant has been filed with the authorities.

The transitive verb "to file [a warrant]" leaves off the preposition and its object, the recipient of the warrant.

Global Court Files Warrant To Arrest Netanyahu

Quite common for a newspaper headline to use the tersest form.
Compare: "to lodge [a complaint]" which could also be supplemented with a prepositional phrase, e.g. "before the commission" or "with the authorities" and so on.  That might appear in a local town newspaper as

Citizens lodge complaint about water quality

